# How to set up MyPackage.targets file to add all dll's into the bin/debug or bin/Release folder?

Tags: c#, msbuild, nuget

I am learning NuGet. I am sure that this is not an uncommon task. I have some native dll's that need to be added to the final output. There are 25 dll's total but only 7 of them can be added as references directly.

I currently have a NuGet package that adds the 7 references directly by using the following structure:

```
build
    x64
        reference1.dll
        ...
        reference7.dll
        TheOthers1.dll
        ...
        TheOthers20.dll
    MyPackage.targets
lib
    net472
        reference1.dll
        reference2.dll
        reference3.dll
        reference4.dll
        reference5.dll
        reference6.dll
        reference7.dll
```

My targets file looks like this:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <NativeLibs Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)**\*.dll" />
    <None Include="@(NativeLibs)">
      <Link>%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

My project output ends up looking like this:

```
bin/Debug
    Reference1.dll
    ...
    Reference7.dll
    x64
        reference1.dll
        ...
        reference7.dll
        TheOthers1.dll
        ...
        TheOthers20.dll
```

When I run the app I get:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'reference1.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.'

If I hand copy the dll's in the x64 folder into the bin/Debug folder the app runs.

How do I structure the .targets file to copy all the dll's that are in build/x64 into bin/Debug or bin/release?

Comment: have you tried looking at a package that also has native assemblies, maybe sqlite, to see how they do it?

Comment: @zivkan - Wow...there is a lot going on with SQLite that I do not understand. From what I can tell with my limited knowledge is that the SQLite.Interop.dll gets copied to the x64 folder just like my dll's. Is there something that tells the app to look for SQLite.Interop.dll inside x64 folder when it needs SQLite.Interop.dll instead of just bin/Debug? In my case my files are there as well but the app can't seem to find them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For native DLL's, always always without fail set the `<OutDir>` property. That determines where the compiled binary will be. That will look something like:

```
<OutDir>bla bla bla\bin\$(Configuration)\</OutDir>
```

Notice how it also must end with a backslash.

For managed DLL's, always always without fail set the `<OutputPath>` property. That determines where the compiled managed assembly will be. That will look something like:

```
<OutputPath>bla bla bla\bin\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
```

Notice they both go to the same place?

Comment: @C Johnson - Using <OutDir>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\bin\$(Configuration)\</OutDir> worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: Another note: To keep things clean, I always like to also define where the *.obj files and other intermediate garbage goes. Define the property `<IntDir>` too. And point it someplace out of the way.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue. I resolved this by using "Copy" function. See an example bellow:

```
<Target Name="CopyREsources" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Copy
       SourceFiles="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)PDFtoPrinter.exe"
       DestinationFiles="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\bin\$(Configuration)\PDFtoPrinter.exe"
       Condition="!Exists('$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\bin\$(Configuration)\PDFtoPrinter.exe')" />
</Target>
```

The full code is available [here](https://github.com/svishnevsky/PDFtoPrinter/blob/master/PDFtoPrinter/build/PDFtoPrinter.targets).

Comment: That looks like it would work as well as C Johnson's answer below. Thank you for your contribution.